# SSRS calculate timedifference between two times HH:MM:SS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I want to know the time difference between two times.

i have 2 string in format HH:MM:SS that i want to compare and know the timedifference

(string) starttime = 12:13:14 AND (string) endtime = 12:13:18 >> the difference should be 4 seconds

I tried something and normally i think that the datediff should do the magic.

`DateDiff("s",CDate(Fields!starttime.Value) , CDate(Fields!endtime.Value))`

After that i would convert the seconds to a timestamp HH:MM:SS

But the reponse is always 0 (seconds)

Can anyone help me out with this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested but...

If you are only checking times that occur on the same day then you could add an arbitrary date before the time.

Something like

```
=DateDiff("s",
          CDate("2020-01-01 " & Fields!starttime.Value) , 
          CDate("2020-01-01 " & Fields!endtime.Value)
         )
```

Comment: Thank you ! I added 
Format(DateAdd("s", DateDiff("s",
          CDate("2020-01-01 " & Fields!starttime.Value) , 
          CDate("2020-01-01 " & Fields!endtime.Value)
         ), "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss")